# Progressive web apps and ASP.net routing

Tags: asp.net, web, routes, progressive-web-apps, progressive

What I’m trying to achieve is provide users with a personalised ASP.net routed URL that they can add to their phone’s home screen. When they tap the icon it opens their personalised page PWA standalone looking almost like a native app.

For example they go to *example.com/myaccount/myuserid* and add it to their home page. That puts the icon on their phone. When they tap the icon they get their own data in the myaccount page.

Except I can’t figure out how to do that. Much research followed by much trial and error has failed to find a way. The web forms page I want them to get to is, say, *example.com/myaccount/default.aspx* and *default.aspx* sees *Page.RouteData.Values("userid") = “myuserid”*

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

After further experimentation, trial and much error I’ve concluded that PWA and ASP.net routing just don’t work together. Not only can I not achieve what I want but the four browsers I tried – Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox - all responded to variations in web manifests in different ways and that really isn’t something I can put in front of users.

Furthermore the offline page service worker from PWABuilder caused the offline page to pop up in all the wrong places so reluctantly I’ve abandoned this project which is a shame.

It may be possible to develop an ASP.net PWA starting from ground zero but I can’t find a way to retrofit. Perhaps someone more skilled than I can.